# Как выбрасывать ошибку если отсутствует Content-type в заголовке запроса?

Tags: json, xml, spring, jaxb

Есть рест-сервис на spring + jaxb такого вида:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Users add(@RequestBody Users users,
                              @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String id) {
        return service.add(id, users.getUsers());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Users findById(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) throws Exception {
        return service.find(id);
    }
}
```

используется библиотека jaxb для получения body в формате xml.
Сейчас все работает ок, передаем в теле запроса информацию о пользователе и получаем, но требуется расширение сервиса, чтобы он мог работать как с xml, так и с json.

Требуется, чтобы при отсутствуюещем заголовке Content-Type:application/xml выбрасывалась ошибка. Для метода POST все работает, а GET всегда возвращает результат вне зависимости от того, какой заголовок передать.

Как сделать так, чтобы выбрасывалась ошибка или можно было бы управлять, что ожидаем получить, xml или json?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST, accept = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, ...})

Comment: пардон, не "accept", a "consumes"

Comment: @aleshka-batman идея ругается на эту запись attrubute value must be constant

Comment: Посмотрите, что принимает  consumes и выберите то, что больше вам подходит из MediaType (там есть как енамы, так и стринги).

Comment: @aleshka-batman я имел ввиду, что запись вида @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})    не рабочий вариант

Comment: основываясь на вашем ответе нашел решение consumes="application/json"  отсюда https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
 попробуйте так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Users add(@RequestBody Users users,
                              @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String id) {
        return service.add(id, users.getUsers());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes={"application/xml"})
    public @ResponseBody Users findById(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) throws Exception {
        return service.find(id);
    }
}
```

То есть, следует добавить consumes.